# Finding Keys when iterating through a 2-dimensional dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

We are using a helpdesksystem which has an API and alot tickets created come from monitoring solutions like Nagios. The format is always the same, the problem is reported with "PROBLEM: description of the problem" and the Resolvement is reported with "OK: description of the problem". I now want to merge those two tickets where a problem and ok message have been posted in a specific timeframe (5minutes). Therefor:

I create a dictionary with the values of tickets from a helpdesk system. 
The structure looks like this:

```
dictTickets[IssueID] = Subject, Date
```

IssueID = the unique identifier of the ticket.

I then check all Subjects from the "OK"-Messages and iterate through the dictionary to see if there was a PROBLEM-Message with the same Subject:

```
if any(tickets['Subject'][len(TermOk):] == first for first, second in dictProblems.values()):
```

Now comes the question: 
If the same message is identified, i would need the key from the tickets-dictionary to identify the Ticket ID. I have the ticket ID from the OK-Message since i iterate through all of them, but i don't know how to get to the key from the dictionary where the value was matched.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` will stop at the first match, and won't tell you which one it is.

It's better to build a list comprehension with the matches and loop on dictionary key+values to test the values and yield the corresponding keys

```
search_for = tickets['Subject'][len(TermOk):]
result = [ticket_id for ticket_id,(first, second) in dictProblems.items() if search_for == first]
if result:
   # there are matches
   # print them or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()` with a generator expression:

```
next(ticket_id for ticket_id, (subject, _) in dictProblems.items() if tickets['Subject'][len(TermOk):] == subject)
```

You can also specify a default value for `next()` as the second argument so that if a ticket is not found with the given subject, it will return `None`, so that you can use it as your `if` condition as well, in place of `any()`:

```
ticket_id = next((ticket_id for ticket_id, (subject, _) in dictProblems.items() if tickets['Subject'][len(TermOk):] == subject), None)
if ticket_id:
     do_something(ticket_id)
```

Since a ticket ID is likely to be unique, `next()` is a good fit as it will return the value of the first match it finds.